# How to convert the value of DATE property of IUpdateHistoryEntry to readable format

Tags: c++, date, time, interface, com

Can not understand how to convert [DATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386422(v=vs.85).aspx) type to redable format.
As I understood type DATE is `typedef double DATE;`. In my case i get value 42463.4. How to conver this type to redable format like day/month/year/hours/minutes/seconds? Thanks.

Comment: `VarBstrFromDate`, `VariantTimeToSystemTime`

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot.